# I need to left join by date but other variable has POSIxct

Tags: r, date, left-join

I have two different variables which I need to combine with date column. I am using left_join function. However, the date form in other variable is POSIxct form. How can I turn this to different form? It seems like it is now "2014-01-29 UTC"

I put on the other variable mutate(date=as.Date(substr(Date,1,10),format="%Y-%m-%d"))%>%

Comment: please show some of your data, no one can comment about it in this way

Comment: It will be extremely challenging to answer your question without at least a sample of your data. Please [edit] your question with the output of `dput(data)` or `dput(head(data))` if your data is very large. See [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/) for more.